# Подключится с помощью компонента websockets

Tags: delphi, websocket

На моей локальной машине есть сайт, к нему нужно подключить приложение на *Delphi*. Для этого я хочу воспользоваться пакетом **[websocket](http://websockets.esegece.com)** , а именно компонентом `sgcWebSocketClient`.
Токен я уже получил, и теперь нужно создать ws соединение.
На [websockets.esegece.com](http://websockets.esegece.com/#wsfeatures) написано, что нужно прописать строку `ws://localhost/sgc/auth/session/:token` для своего локального сайта, только я не пойму, какому свойству это приписывать?
У этого компонента есть свойство **Host**, но там указывают или **IP**, или **DNS**